# Images do not match using PIL.ImageChops?

Tags: image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: images do not match
```

when I try to use

```
ImageChops.multiply(Perlin,fem1)
```

Because Perlin.mode is "L" and fem1.mode is "RGB".

Perlin.convert('RGB') does not work to change the mode, so what should I do instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a proper Minimal Complete Verifiable Example as Stack Overflow requires, including the necessary `import` statements and any images you use.

Comment: Some reading: [mcve] & [ask]